# Unable to add Coredata Framework in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data

In my application I have accidentally deleted CoreData framework from my resource folder.
But after that when I tried to add framework from build settings,Coredata.framework is missing from the list. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have deleted the framework instead of removing the reference.

Find CoreData.framwork on another PC, copy the complete framework and paste it in the folder of frameworks in your PC(/Applications/Xcode 5.0.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks).

Answer (score 0):

First see if CoreData.framework is still in the list of your selected frameworks. If it is, select it and click the minus sign `-` to remove it. Then add it again.

The problem is that it is still marked as added in the configuration, but cannot find the appropriate file in your bundle because you deleted it.